# how would you speak this in big o notation?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, binary-search

A binary search has a time complexity of:

O(log(n))

How would you speak this representation to a technical person?  Would you speak:

"O of log of n"

or possibly:

"O of log to the n"

Or would you speak this in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "*O* of log *n*", and that's the only pronunciation I've heard others use.

Comment: Sometimes "Big O of log n", if someone wants to make sure no one understands "little o of log n". But this is more common the other way around.